# Работа с классом TCanvas

Tags: c++, c++builder

> На прямой есть `m` точек (задается пользователем), нужно найти точку от
>   которой расстояние к остальным было бы минимальным.

Как мне отобразить точки на экране в C++ Builder?

Comment: "расстояние к остальным" - это какой язык?

Answer (score 3):

Можно так: `Form1->Canvas->Pixels[x][y] = clWhite ; /*0xFFFFFF*/`

Answer (score 2):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,
      TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    //параметры 
    Form1->Canvas->Pen->Color = clBlue;
    Form1->Canvas->Pen->Width = 5;
    Form1->Canvas->Brush->Color = clRed;
    // отрисовка 
    Form1->Canvas->MoveTo(X, Y); // Переходит к координатам
    Form1->Canvas->LineTo(X, Y);   // Рисует точечку

}
```

Comment: Почему на канве, а не в CHART?

Comment: @Builder за chart  никто не спрашивал. А если вы хотите отобразить 10000000 точек, то ваш chart повиснет - нужен opengl, я же не пишу почему в ответе не opengl. Но ваш вариант решения можете опубликовать как ответ.

Comment: @BuilderC потому что в задаче нет CHART. ну и как ответили выше захлебнется.